# List forked github repositories without pull request

Tags: github

I have forked a number of GitHub repositories (some of them using the on-line file editor), sent pull-requests, they were merged. How can I list the repositories that I have forked that do NOT have any outstanding pull-requests or for that matter any changes not yet integrated into the original?

The real objective is to remove all the "clean" repositories.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to (using GitHub API):

- [list your repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories)
- for each repo, [get it](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) and look if there is a "source" (which means your repo is a fork)
- for each fork, [list pull requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests)
- for each pull request, [check if it has been merged](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-if-a-pull-request-has-been-merged)
- for the forks without pull requests (or merged only pull requests): [delete the fork](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository).